# Azure Functions V1 linking wrong version of the RestSharp.dll

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Guys I know that the azure functions cli has a dependency with RestSharp.dll and I think that is conflicting with one of my Azure Functions.

I am getting a runtime type exception
System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type 'RestSharp.IAuthenticator' from assembly 'RestSharp, Version=105.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.'

Now my azure function is dependent on RestSharp nuget Version 104.4.0.0. There is no reference in my project to Version 105.2.3.0.  Here is the interesting thing. In my despair I searched my entire computer for the culprit dll version 105.2.3.0 and I found it at AppData\local\Azure.Functions.Cli\1.0.12

Is that it ? Is the Azure functions runtime trying to link with its  RestSharp.dll version instead of the dll version of my project ?

Answer (score 1):

Runtime should technically load version 104.4.0.0. However it is still loading the version referred by the runtime (105.2.3.0). I was able to verify this behavior. Have filed a bug for this https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/2832.

In the meantime is it possible to do one of the following:

1. Update the code to use 105.2.3.0, I see RestSharp.IAuthenticator type is present. It is under a different namespace. There should be another method exposing the same functionality
2. If the function app is not being used in prod. You could use the beta runtime. You should not encounter this issue in beta runtime (v2.x)